# Make a program automatically add text fields in java

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextfield

Maybe there is a similar question to this, but I couldn't find a one.

Id like my program ( awt or swing ) to add controls ( like text fields ) automatically.

For example : A dialog program has 10 fields for inputting names, but I need 11 so by pressing a button a new field will appear.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example using [`Box`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html):

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MultiJComponentsTest extends JFrame
{
    private JButton btnAdd;
    private JPanel centerPanel;
    private Box vBox;

    public MultiJComponentsTest()
    {
        super("The Title");
        btnAdd = new JButton("Add new JTextField!");
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                vBox.add(new JTextField(20));
                pack();
            }

        });
        vBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel contentPanel = (JPanel) getContentPane();
        contentPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.add(btnAdd, "South");
        contentPanel.add(centerPanel, "Center");
        centerPanel.add(vBox);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new MultiJComponentsTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some useful ***Duplicates*** of your question:

- [java - How would I dynamically add swing component to gui on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279435/java-how-would-i-dynamically-add-swing-component-to-gui-on-click)
- [How do I dynamically add Panels to other panels at runtime in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169799/how-do-i-dynamically-add-panels-to-other-panels-at-runtime-in-java)